# Upload file in Google Cloud Storage like a local file using Axios and Form-data

Tags: node.js, stream, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) npm packages to upload a local file.

Here's the basic code structure:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

async function upload()
{
    var path_str = '/path/to/file.pdf';
    var form_obj = new FormData();
    form_obj.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream(path_str));

    var req_obj = {};
    req_obj['url'] = 'https://post-url';
    req_obj['method'] = 'post';
    req_obj['data'] = form_obj;
    return await axios(req_obj);
}
```

I would like to do the same thing for a file in Google Cloud Storage. In other words, instead of downloading the file from cloud storage to a local destination, and then using `fs.createReadStream` to access it, I'd prefer to do the equivalent of `fs.createReadStream` on the file while it is in cloud storage.

In the Google Cloud Storage npm package, `File` has a method called [createReadStream](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#createReadStream), but that did not work when I plugged it into my code.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From the method [createReadStream](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#createReadStream) that you pointed out:

> Create a readable stream to read the contents of the remote file. It can be piped to a writable stream or **listened to for 'data' events to read a file's contents**.

I understand that you are interested on the text marked in bold. Here is an example of how to do it. This code reads the file content without having to download it to your local system. The data object is instance of [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) and it will depend on you how to handle it.

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const fs = require('fs');

const storage = new Storage();

const bucket = storage.bucket('yourBucketName');
const remoteFile = bucket.file('yourFileName')

remoteFile.createReadStream()
    .on('error', function(err) {})
    .on('response', function(response) {
        console.log('Server connected and responded with the specified status and headers.')
     })
    .on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        console.log(data.toString())
     })
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log('End')
     })
```